# Testing DAO and Service / Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

The question has already been asked at Stackoverflow but I haven't found the answer. I can't understand how to test (unit) my DAO and Service layers (you will be able to find the methods I would like to test below). So, there are two opposite notions regarding testing of DAO: the one is not to test it at all, the opposite one is to test it only with in-memory DB. As for service layer there are meaning that method should be tested only if it has business logic. So, frankly I can't even imaging what to do because I'm not sure which the way is correct. At my last pet project I tested DAO by using jUnit only (examle for saveEntity()): I explicitly created entity, populated it, saved it by using DAO-method, when retrieved it, asserted result and explicitly deleted the object from the DB. I'm sure that it is not the proper way to test it. So, please take a look at the code below and give me an advice how to test these layers' methods properly:

**DAO**

```
@Override
public void saveEntity(Artist entity) throws ConstraintViolationException {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveEntity(Artist entity) throws ConstraintViolationException {
    artistDAO.saveEntity(entity);
}
```

I wanted to do it with Mockito but all examples I found not similar to my case.
Thank you for any ideas how to do that.

Comment: We run integration tests with curl or other commands to verify DAO layer code. I am not a fan of DAO unit testing with a whole special database setup

Comment: Robert, is it appropriate practice in commercial development to test DAO? If yes is working DB or in-memory one usually used?

Comment: You can. For all the work though I'm not sure we saw much return on investment. You are constantly updating those tests. Plus we do end to end testing and that catches most things.

Comment: I guess it would depend though. We make full stack webapps here so we don't focus on just the dao layer we care more about the features for the users. If you are someplace that is closer to that layer and that is your focus it might be really important. :-)